# Why $IM(S) \bigoplus Ker(T)=V$ imply that $IM(TS)=IMT$ (attempt added)

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a finite dimension vector field over $\mathbb{F}$. Let $T,S : V \to V$ be two linear transformations. Show that if $IM(S) \bigoplus Ker(T)=V  $ than $IM(TS)=IMT$

My attempt:

I know that in general for finite dimension case this is true that $IM(TS)\subseteq IM(T)$ so I was thinking just to show that $dim(IM(TS))=dim(IM(T))$. from the given I can infer that $$dim (IM(S))+dim(Ker(T))=dim(V)$$
I also know from the rank nulity theorem that: $$dim(IM(TS)) + dim (Ker(TS)=dim(V)$$ and I also tried to write the rank nulity theorem for $T$ and $S$ seperatly and the only thing I could infer is that the equality between the dimenstions of the images and the kernals of $T$ and $S$, meaning $$dim(IM(S))=dim(IM(T))$$ $$dim(Ker(S))=dim(Ker(T))$$

I cannot see how this help me get the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $x \in V =IM(S) \bigoplus Ker(T)$. Write $x$ as $Sy+z$ with $z \in Ker (T)$. Then $Tx=TSy+0\in IM(TS)$, we have proved that any point in $IM(T)$ is contained in $IM(TS)$, as required.

Comment: Briliant, thank you!